# I'm unable to install the Symfony var-dumper component

Tags: 8, composer

I am having issues installing symfony/var-dumper package via composer
the command I ran is

```
composer require symfony/var-dumper
```

The result I get is

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
   - Conclusion: remove drupal/core-recommended 8.9.1
   - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-recommended 8.9.1
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.2
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.1
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.0
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.0-RC2
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.0-RC1
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper v5.1.0-BETA1
   - Installation request for drupal/core-recommended (locked at 8.9.1, required as ^8.8) -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[8.9.1].
   - Conclusion: don't install symfony/var-dumper 5.2.x-dev
   - drupal/core-recommended 8.9.1 requires symfony/console v3.4.41 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.4.41].
   - symfony/console v3.4.41 conflicts with symfony/var-dumper[5.1.x-dev].
   - symfony/var-dumper 5.1.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v3.4.41].
   - symfony/var-dumper 5.1.x-dev conflicts with symfony/console[v3.4.41].
   - Installation request for symfony/var-dumper ^5.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, v5.1.0, v5.1.0-BETA1, v5.1.0-RC1, v5.1.0-RC2, v5.1.1, v5.1.2].
   Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

My composer.json file is

```
{
  "name": "drupal/legacy-project",
  "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer following drupal/drupal layout",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
  "support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
  "repositories": {
    "0": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    "drupal": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
},
  "require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^8.8",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1"
},
  "conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
   "prefer-stable": true,
   "config": {
    "sort-packages": true
},
  "extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "./"
        }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": [
            "homepage",
            "support"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/legacy-project template!               </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I haven't even customized it yet, this is pretty much out of the box at the moment and I am already having issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[drupal/core-recommended 8.9.2](https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/core-recommended#8.9.2) requires [symfony/console v3.4.41](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/console#v3.4.41) while the [currently latest symfony/var-dumper](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/var-dumper#v5.1.2) requires symfony/console at minimum version 4.4. When you run `composer require symfony/var-dumper` without specifying any version it will try to install the currently latest version 5 of the var-dumper. Mismatched dependencies. Error. So simply install a version of the var-dumper that matches the dependencies and can be installed with Symfony 3.4 components.

```
composer require symfony/var-dumper:^4.4
```